# C# Entity Framework - insert value into DatabaseGenerated column

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I have a table that has Primary Key using two columns (`REQID` and `REQ_SUBID`) and I have a trigger that generates these values, but only if they are not defined. In EF representation, I am using DatabaseGenerated attribute

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Column("REQID", Order = 0)]
public string RequestId { get; set; } 

[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Column("REQ_SUBID", Order = 1)]
public int RequestSubId { get; set; }
```

but sometimes I want to set `REQID` value in code and save it into database, but if I try to do it, I get this exception:

> A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'REQID'.

Is here any way how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] on an string property, if you need to automatically generate unic id you can place in in the constructor

```
public class myEntity{
  MyEntity(){
   RequestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
 }
}
```